# C-style casting references

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider the following:

```
template<class T>
struct call_fn;

template< >
struct call_fn< void( ) >
{
    using sig = void ( );
    void * fn;
    void call() &&
    {
        static_cast< sig * >( fn )( );
    }
    auto && change()
    {
        return (call_fn<void __vectorcall( )>&&)(*this);
    }
};

template< >
struct call_fn< void __vectorcall( ) >
{
    using sig = void __vectorcall( );
    void * fn;
    void call() &&
    {
        static_cast< sig * >( fn )( );
    }
    auto && change()
    {
        return (call_fn<void ( )>&&)(*this);
    }
};

void __vectorcall fast()
{}
void  stdd()
{}

void foo()
{
    void * f = fast;
    void * st = stdd;
    call_fn<decltype(stdd)> { f }.change().call();
    call_fn<decltype(fast)> { st }.change().call();
}
```

Or more simply, if you aren't interested in the specific example:

```
template<class T>
struct s
{
    using t = T;
    char f;
};

void foo()
{
    auto y = (s<int>&&)(s<float>());
}
```

In this case, where the objects are identical other than metaprogramming, is this a well defined cast to do c-style? (since it cannot be done any other way using c++ casting)

Comment: Generally speaking, C-style casts should be seen as a red flag that you're doing something wrong. And here you try to create an rvalue reference to a temporary object, an object whose life-time will end immediately making any reference to it invalid at once.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have a class using function traits, and I need to change the convention on the fly. I do this with a member, called `change_convention`, which just changes the type of the object and returns `this`. I do this so the type alias in the structure is changed to the new convention.

Comment: Besides the bad example, it breaks strict aliasing. So either way it's wrong.

Comment: [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please explain the actualy problem you want to solve. If the solution needs a c-style cast then most likely it isnt a solution

Comment: @idclev463035818 There is a type alias in the class. This type alias is based on template arguments. I can recast the class to the same class with different template arguments (preserving the actual object) to change the type alias. That is what I'm doing.

Comment: c-style casts arent bad per se. The problem is just that you are completely on your own while with proper casts the compiler can help you. If no c++ casts can do it this is a good indicator that the c-cast is also wrong

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It's a minimal example. I can, of course, extend it if you all would like.

Comment: not sure if you have to add much more, but apparently this example is not a showcase of your original problem.

Comment: instead of casting the object you should only use the right type in place of the alias, this doesnt require any casting of instances

Comment: @idclev463035818 
examples changed.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Does strict aliasing apply in this example? They are the same type. That's why I tagged language-lawyer

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the temporary lasts till the end of the full-expression so there is no lifetime issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (since it cannot be done any other way using c++ casting)
>
> ```
> (s<int>&&)(s<float>());
> ```

This cast can be done with C++ style cast. The equivalent is:

```
reinterpret_cast<s<int>&&>(s<float>());
```

---

> is this a well defined cast

Reinterpret casting reference to another is well defined.

Accessing through the reinterpreted reference is not well defined in this case. `s<int>` is a distinct type from `s<float>` and there is no `s<int>` object at that address.

---

Note that this is a case where union type punning is exceptionally allowed (common initial sequence of standard layout struct):

```
union U {
    s<float> sf;
    s<int>   si;
};

U u;
u.sf = {};
return u.si.f; // well defined
```

Standard ref:

> [class.mem]
>
> The common initial sequence of two standard-layout struct ([class.prop]) types is the longest sequence of non-static data members and bit-fields in declaration order, starting with the first such entity in each of the structs, such that corresponding entities have layout-compatible types, either both entities are declared with the no_­unique_­address attribute ([dcl.attr.nouniqueaddr]) or neither is, and either both entities are bit-fields with the same width or neither is a bit-field.
>
> In a standard-layout union with an active member of struct type T1, it is permitted to read a non-static data member m of another union member of struct type T2 provided m is part of the common initial sequence of T1 and T2; the behavior is as if the corresponding member of T1 were nominated.

---

Note that reinterpreting address of the first member would also be allowed:

```
s<float> sf{};
return *reinterpret_cast<char*>(&sf); // well defined
```

Standard ref:

> [expr.reinterpret.cast]
>
> An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of a different type.
> When a prvalue v of object pointer type is converted to the object pointer type “pointer to cv T”, the result is `static_­cast<cv T*>(static_­cast<cv void*>(v))`.
>
> [expr.static.cast]
>
> A prvalue of type “pointer to cv1 void” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv2 T”, where T is an object type and cv2 is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, cv1. ... if the original pointer value points to an object a, and there is an object b of type T (ignoring cv-qualification) that is pointer-interconvertible with a, **the result is a pointer to b**.
>
> [basic.compound]

> Two objects a and b are pointer-interconvertible if:
>
> - ...
> - one is a standard-layout class object and the other is the first non-static data member of that object, ...
> - ...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude there's a "common initial sequence" exception , maybe it applies in this case

Comment: @eerorika Interesting, I was also under the impression that this was legal C but illegal C++ type punning, even if both `s` specializations just wrap a `char`. Would you consider including a standard reference that one may read up on?

Comment: @dfri Added standard ref. To my understanding, C is much more flexible with allowing union punning (at least since C99).